# boost asio ssl async_write send me mostly gibberish

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, openssl, boost-asio

I'm in the process of converting my non secure socket to ssl, using boost::asio::ssl

While everything was working fine with non-ssl, async_write send me mostly gibberish.

The funny thing is when I put a sleep(1) between every async_write, I get mostly good data, with a little gibberish (something like that "?????@??" )

The faster I send data the most gibberish it gets... I'm completely lost on this problem !

initSSLConnection :

```
boost::asio::ssl::context *m_context = new boost::asio::ssl::context(m_acceptor.io_service(), boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
 m_context->set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
                       | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
                       | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
 m_context->set_password_callback(boost::bind(&Server::get_password, this));
 m_context->use_certificate_chain_file("./ssl_key/cert.pem");
 m_context->use_private_key_file("./ssl_key/key.pem", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
```

write on Socket :

```
while (1) {
boost::asio::async_write(m_socket,                                              
                          boost::asio::buffer(ss.str().c_str(), ss.str().size()),
                          boost::bind(&MyClass::done_writing,                        
                                      shared_from_this())
                          );
}
```

Here's what I get when I do not put sleep(1) :

```
`?D`?@?pR???c??_?@?pR??c?@?pR??␌?@???␌?D◆?P0AE0004J0??@?⎻RP0AE0004J0??@?XJ┘?D◆?P0AE0004J0??X?┬±?>   ␋┌≤C5700␌??┬±??>    ␋┌≤C5700␌?????┐?>   ␋┌≤C5700␌?????????┬±??┐?

                       ?┴?^>    ␋┌≤C5700␌??

                                           ?┴?^^>   ␋┌≤C5700␌?????

                                                                      ?┴?>  ␋┌≤C5700␌?V
          ??@

             ?┴?>   ␋┌≤C◆????␋┌≤F1DA0?│?ADO14F⎼␋???@?⎻R
                                                           ?    ␋┌≤D9A90?┌?┬±?

                                                                              ?┴?┬±?

    ?┴??┐?ADO14F⎼␋⎻??@?⎻R?
?
 6A7BD600?≠??┌?◆????␋┌≤21ADC?├???
␉
◆????␋┌≤21ADC?├???
◆????␋┌≤21ADC?├??◆????␋┌≤21ADC?├??
```

It seems that it is encoded or something...

I connect to the server via this command line :

```
openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect 127.0.0.1:4242
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are interleaving writes..

```
while (1) {
boost::asio::async_write(m_socket,                                              
                          boost::asio::buffer(ss.str().c_str(), ss.str().size()),
                          boost::bind(&MyClass::done_writing,                        
                                      shared_from_this())
                          );
}
```

You should only do the next `async_write`, once the first one completes - i.e. in the `done_writing` handler. This is why you get crap as you make more calls...

Comment: How come I did not get this crap when it was non-ssl ?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the [asio reference counted buffer example](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_5_3/doc/html/boost_asio/example/buffers/reference_counted.cpp) for a method that will probably fix this for you

Comment: @Nim : that was right, no more gibberish... Can't say it won't give me some hassle, but what you gonna do ;-) +1 for the fast & right answer

Comment: @TheSquad, been there, done that, and have all the badges... hth